# Code not performing according to the parameters

Tags: python-3.x

Its a part of a code I made for making a simple virtual assistant. In it there are certain parameters for certain actions ,but as I run this code the only thing it does is that it searches whatever I speak in wikipedia ,for example if I say "open YouTube" then instead of opening YouTube it searches the command in wikipedia and speaks out the result. For every command it just ignores  the parameters and searches it in wikipedia. I am using python 3.10.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
wishMe()
while True:
# if 1:
    query = takeCommand().lower()

    # Logic for executing tasks based on query
    if 'who is' or 'what is' in query:
        speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
        query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
        results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
        speak("According to Wikipedia")
        print(f'Astra: {results}')
        speak(results)

    elif 'open youtube' in query:
        webbrowser.open("youtube.com")

    elif 'open google' in query:
        def open(url='google.com', new=2, autoraise=True):
            webbrowser.open("google.com")

    elif 'open stackoverflow' in query:
        webbrowser.open("stackoverflow.com")   

    elif 'the time' in query:
        strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")    
        speak(f"Sir, the time is {strTime}")

    elif 'open v s code' in query:
        codePath = "C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe"
        os.startfile(codePath)
```

Comment: You should add a `print(query)` line before the if statements and post the result here so we can help you find the problem.

Comment: You should use the debugger to narrow down your problem, not rely on OS to debug your code.

Comment: `if 'who is' in query or 'what is' in query:`

Comment: It was a silly mistake in the code which @rioV8 pointed out. Thanks everyone for helping.